# Refresh a ListView if I change the content of the ListItem

Tags: android

I have a ListView in my android activity. And I populate the ListView by sub-class the BaseAdaptor (which returns a View in getView() method).

What if in my click listener of a button in a list item view, I

- change the text of the TextView in the List item view
  or
- change the dimension of the list item view by adding/removing children of the list item view

What is an efficient to refresh my listView? I don't want the listView to re-trigger a query since there is no data change.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

if you just change the content of your Children View, you have not more to do than `TextView.setText(newText)`.

If you change the count of your ListView childrens, you have to call `BaseAdaptor.notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: I dont' change the count of the ListView. I just change number of children of the ViewGroup in 1 of the ListView Item.

Answer (score 0):

I was about to suggest that you `invalidate()`, but you don't want to trigger a redraw, so I can only suggest that some form of global flag is your best bet. Set the flag, invalidate or redraw and query (and reset) the flag in OnDraw()

Comment: I just don't want to trigger a requery. But when you said invalidate(), you talked about invalidate() the ListView() or the view of the list item?  Moreover, I can't call invalidate() in my OnClickListener(). Isn't android guard against updating the UI in a non-UI thread?